# How does a computer convert a floating point number into decimal

Tags: computer-science

For example if I were to take the binary floating point `00000000011010000000000000000000` (1.101)
How would the computer convert this to the decimal of it (1.675)?

Comment: Not to be picky, but (1) what you've got is 1.625, not 1.675.  (2) Internally, the computer would be representing it using IEEE notation, `0-01111111-10100000000000000000000` with a sign, 127-excess exponent, and a normalized mantissa.  But the operation described by @user253751 is correct.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maths, basically.

What's the whole part? It's 1. Cut off the 1, multiply by 10, what's the whole part? It's 6. Cut off the 6, multiply by 10, what's the whole part? It's 7. Cut off the 7, multiply by 10, what's the whole part? It's 5. Cut off the 5 and now the number is 0 so you're done. Ever written a function to convert integers to decimal? Like that but in reverse.

Unless you care a lot about rounding error. Then it gets [really complicated](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/float-precisionfrom-zero-to-100-digits-2/). Most people - [even the ones who wrote the standard library, probably!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62661223/sprintf-formatting-problem-for-doubles-with-high-precision) - don't bother with *extreme* accuracy. The authors of the precise conversion algorithm Ryu̅ [wrote a scientific paper about it](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3192366.3192369).

Comment: I would presume floating point accuracy is similar to 1 = 0.9999999... because of 1/3

Comment: @HummingCloud there's no 0.999999999... floating point value - only 1.